Extract bitmap from cloud storage like google photos
I'm trying to extract a bitmap from a video that isn't on the device, suchas a cloud media app like Google Photos. I have no issues when the video was recorded with the actual device, but if the video is synced to google photos from another device I just get back null.
edit: Updated to download into memory
@Composable
fun VideoThumbnail(uri: Uri) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var bitmap by remember { mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(null) }

    LaunchedEffect(uri) {
        val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
        val contentResolver: ContentResolver = context.contentResolver

        try {
            if (uri.authority?.contains("com.google.android.apps.photos") == true) {
                // Download the file into memory
                val inputStream: InputStream? = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
                val tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp_video", null, context.cacheDir)
                val outputStream = FileOutputStream(tempFile)
                inputStream?.copyTo(outputStream)
                inputStream?.close()
                outputStream.close()

                retriever.setDataSource(tempFile.absolutePath)
            } else {
                retriever.setDataSource(context, uri)
            }

            // Try to get the thumbnail at 1 second (1000000 microseconds)
            bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(1000000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC)
            if (bitmap == null) {
                // Fallback to the first frame if 1 second frame is not available
                bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(0, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Handle exceptions
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            retriever.release()
        }
    }

    bitmap?.let {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            bitmap = it.asImageBitmap(),
            contentDescription = "Video Thumbnail",
        )
    }
}


@Dai it's defined at bitmap?.let, but is null

Sorry I forgot about Kotlin's it.

if use uri and that uri is not available in your storage then its should return null first you download this video or image in your storage then you get bitmap. Because when you convert uri into bitmap then its must be in your local storage.

The URI is available in the cloud media storage. It's weird that Google rolled this out but does not provide documentation on how to download that image for use. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2024/02/cloud-photos-now-available-in-android-photo-picker.html

I updated my code to download into memory and same result
